# rank with LOD caculation in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table that looks liek this

```
column1 column2 value
a        d        10
a        e        20
b        d        30
b        e         40

and I want to get the rank of the value without considering column1 so I use and LOD to first get the total value with:  {EXCLUDE [column1]: SUM([value])}

this works and produces

  rank
d  40
e  60
d  40
e  60

BUT what I want to do is get the rank. So I'd like 

  rank
d  2
e  1
d  2
e  1

when I do this  RANK( {EXCLUDE [Pct Of Adv Buckets]: SUM([Notional])} )

I get an error "all fields must be aggregate or constants when using table calcualtions. Can you advise how to get teh rank.
```

Comment: do you want to exclude the column1 from calculation or do you want to exclude it from the report?

Comment: can you share your tableau workbook so that i can change it and give it to you.as I am unable to understand your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried RANK(SUM({EXCLUDE [Column1]: SUM([Value])}))
I have a different raking, but I think that is that you are looking for.